# Elegant way to form specialized tuples or triples

Tags: scala, functional-programming, enumeration

I am trying to create the following :

```
(1, 1)
(1, 2)
(1, 3)
...
(9,9)
```

in Scala.  I tried doing something like:

`(1 to 9) zip (1 to 9)`, but thats not quite right.  Is there a clean functional way to do this?  Hopefully whatever solution there is can easily be extended to triples, and so forth.

Comment: I might be mistaken, but I believe the term "tuple" refers to tuples of arbitrary length, while if you want to specifically refer to tuples of length 2, you want "duple".  Just an observation.

Comment: Perhaps the term I should have used was Pair vs Triple

Comment: @TrippKinetics although there is such distinction in general, it's very uncommon in scala community

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a for-comprehension over 2 ranges from `1` to `9`.

```
val tuples = for (x <- 1 to 9; y <- 1 to 9) yield (x, y)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also use a desugared version

```
val tuples = (1 to 9).flatMap(y => (1 to 9).map(y => (x,y)) )
```

or an arithmetic one

```
val tuples = (0 until 9*9).map(i => (i/9+1, i%9+1) )
```

or a stream-based one

```
val s:Stream[Int] = (1 to 9).toStream #::: s
val tuples = (1 to 9).flatMap(List.fill(9)(_)).zip(s)
```

or a symmetric collection-based

```
val tuples = (1 to 9).map(List.fill(9)(_)).flatten zip
  List.fill(9)((1 to 9)).flatten
```